# Make a FlxSprite behave as the child of another FlxSprite

Tags: sprite, haxe, haxeflixel, flixel

In Flixel, [you cannot add a `FlxSprite` to another one](http://haxeflixel.com/documentation/flixel-display-list/), like you could with Flash API (Sprites were subclasses of `DisplayObject`). So if you want 2 Sprites to behave like parent and child, you still have to animate them **separately**. This can become a nightmare if you use Tweens too.

For example, imagine a rotating spaceship that has attached thrusters, or a moving character that wears an armor, hat, shield etc.

Is there a way to have a 'child' Sprite acting like it was added into a 'parent' one, so that it updates **automatically** its position, scale and rotation accordingly? For example, during their `FlxGroup`'s `update()` function?

I'm interested in HaxeFlixel 3.3.1, although it doesn't really matter, as this applies for all versions and ports of Flixel.

Edit: I noticed that HaxeFlixel features [`FlxSpriteGroup`](http://api.haxeflixel.com/flixel/group/FlxSpriteGroup.html), which is supposed to handle the multiple Sprites. But this is a new feature, and I'm pretty sure that flixel developers are using different approaches for the rest of the flixel ports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HaxeFlixel provides [`FlxSpriteGroup`](http://api.haxeflixel.com/flixel/group/FlxSpriteGroup.html) and [`FlxNestedSprite`](http://api.haxeflixel.com/flixel/addons/display/FlxNestedSprite.html) which both can be used to have some sprites behaving as a group. In both approaches, I had a problem updating the `angle` and `scale` properties, however updating the position seems to work fine.

If you are not interested to animate the sprites separately, and painting one sprite over another is what you're after, `FlxSprite`'s [`stamp()`](http://api.haxeflixel.com/flixel/FlxSprite.html?#stamp) function could be what you need (e.g. draw a helmet over your character)

Comment: Did you open any issues about the angle/scale? I'm running into a problem with scale as well for `FlxSpriteGroup`. `FlxNestedSprite` doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: 1) FlxNestedSprite is an extra library you can import: flixel-addons https://github.com/HaxeFlixel/flixel-addons

Comment: 2) But FlxNestedSprite had the same issues, so i opened a issue https://github.com/HaxeFlixel/flixel-addons/issues/156

Comment: 3) I shared a fix, not merged yet : https://github.com/HaxeFlixel/flixel-addons/pull/157

Answer (score 1):

There's a limited version of this available using: http://api.haxeflixel.com/flixel/addons/display/FlxNestedSprite.html

Comment: true, but as you said it's limited. I have issues working with the scaling : https://groups.google.com/forum/embed/?place=forum/haxeflixel&showsearch=true&showpopout=true&showtabs=true&parenturl=http://haxeflixel.com/forum/&afterlogin&pli=1#!topic/haxeflixel/AY5RhvKOI3k